# Create issues via Email in redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm a Redmine user and administrator. I want to configure redmine to allow issue creation and commenting via email. I need to configure it in such a way that it reads emails from standard input (not from imap pop3 or email server).But when I'm executing a rake task its showing error like given below.Can any one please help to resolve it

```
bash-4.1# rake -f Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=smtprelay.intra.coriant.com port=25  --trace
** Invoke redmine:email:receive_imap (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute redmine:email:receive_imap
rake aborted!



/data/r/data/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
/data/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `invoke_task'
/data/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/data/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'edmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/data/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/data/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/data/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/data/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/data/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/data/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/data/redmine/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/data/redmine/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `<main
```

Comment: That's the stack trace, the error seems to be missing from the post... could you locate it and add it to your post?

Comment: bash-4.1# rake -f Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=smtprelay.intra.coriant.com port=25  --trace
** Invoke redmine:email:receive_imap (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute redmine:email:receive_imap
rake aborted!

Comment: It seems that something is still missing - the _error message_. Look again at your trace, and see if you haven't missed something.